# Can I use Accounts framework for custom login?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, account

I'm using OAuth2 authentication and want to use `Accounts` framework for this. Everything looked good except that I can't access `refreshToken` property in `ACAccountCredential`.

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open class ACAccountCredential : NSObject {
    public init!(oAuthToken token: String!, tokenSecret secret: String!)
    public init!(oAuth2Token token: String!, refreshToken: String!, expiryDate: Date!)

    // This property is only valid for OAuth2 credentials
    open var oauthToken: String!
}
```

To renew accessToken, it seems like I need to use `ACAccountStore`.

```
@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open class ACAccountStore : NSObject {
    // Saves the account to the account database. If the account is unauthenticated and the associated account
    // type supports authentication, the system will attempt to authenticate with the credentials provided.
    // Assuming a successful authentication, the account will be saved to the account store. The completion handler
    // for this method is called on an arbitrary queue.
    open func saveAccount(_ account: ACAccount!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ACAccountStoreSaveCompletionHandler!)

    open func requestAccessToAccounts(with accountType: ACAccountType!, options: [AnyHashable : Any]! = [:], completion: ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler!)


    // Call this if you discover that an ACAccount's credential is no longer valid.
    open func renewCredentials(for account: ACAccount!, completion completionHandler: ACAccountStoreCredentialRenewalHandler!)
}
```

There are couple things in `ACAccountStore` which is not so clear. What is `account database`? Is it a keychain so I can also use in other apps? or it is kind of private `CoreData` database?

I made a subclass to override `renewCredential` but the problem is I can't access `refreshToken` value in `ACAccountCrendential`. Am I doing right? or this `Accounts` framework is kind of legacy which nobody uses?